# Mark certain axis text in bold

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to mark the text that matches "GTAAACATCCTCGACTGGAAGC" bold in my plot. 
What I have tried is this:

```
theme(axis.text.y=element_text(face=ifelse(levels(miR10b_30a$ID2)==
                                          "GTAAACATCCTCGACTGGAAGC","bold")))
```

It gives this error:

> Error in check.length("fontface") :    'gpar' element 'fontface' must
>   not be length 0

Any other good ways of doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is `ifelse`. 
Here is an example that should clarify the point:

```
vec_fontface <- ifelse(levels(iris$Species)=="setosa","bold","plain")
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) + geom_point() +
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(face=vec_fontface))
```

[image]