# How to make compare two lists

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to bold some of the name in the x-axis. For example,

```
fruits = c("apple", "orange", "watermelons")
juice_content = c(10, 1, 1000)
weight = c(5, 2, 2000)
df = data.frame(fruits, juice_content, weight)
df = gather(df, compare, measure, juice_content:weight, factor_key=TRUE)
plot = ggplot(df, aes(fruits, measure, fill = compare)) + 
         geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge())
```

I want the label `orange` be bold in the x-axis.

Edit. With the helps from the comment, I am able to get the x-axis bolded. However, I am not able to compare the two lists.

Here we have 
`fruits = c("apple", "orange", "watermelons")`

let's say that this list has become longer: `fruits = c("apple", "orange", "watermelons","pears","banana","mango")`and we have another shorter list of fruits list: `short_fruit=c("orange","apple","mango")`

How can I compare them?

I tried `vec_fontface <- ifelse(fruit == short_fruit,"bold","plain")`
but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: I think you want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223150/mark-certain-axis-text-in-bold).

Comment: @JohnnyTon I was at work and I could not see your comment till now. Let me clarify what you want. Do you want orange, apple, and mango in bold font? If not, can you tell us what you are after clearly.

Comment: @jazzurro yes! But I want the code to be more general, like with respect to the whole list rather than something like : 
`vec_fontface <- ifelse(fruit == c("orange","apple","mango") ,"bold","plain")`

Comment: @JohnnyTon By saying "more general", what do you mean? Isn't `vec_fontface <- ifelse(fruit %in% c("orange","apple","mango") ,"bold","plain")` enough?