# Making bold certain y-axis labels on a gglplot matrix heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe called [melted_cormat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8dff.png), and I am trying to use it to plot a heatmap in ggplot. I also have a list of new_names = c(a,b,c) that I would like to make bold on the heatmap. I managed to plot the [heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnpmm.png), but I have been having issues making bold the list of names that I have.  Since the new_names that I want to make bold appear more than once in the Var1 and Var2 columns I am plotting, I used the list of new_names to create additional columns on the [melted_cormat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8dff.png) namely "names_to_consider" and "names_to_color" to try and use these to specify the names that I want to bold or color. However this is not working, the best I managed to do was make bold everything, or bold one line and skip the other, but not only the three names that I want, eg. this [heatmap2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X6hX.png) where **a, b and c appear in bold**. I have included my code below. I have looked up at other pages that helped with the code to specify certain names to bold (e.g [Mark certain axis text in bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223150/mark-certain-axis-text-in-bold)), the only difference now is that the names appear in a matrix. Thank you in advance for all your help.

```
new_names = c("a","b","c")

#I tried to narrow down the axis labels to consider, and defined them as those points in the matrix where the Var label is the same as the Var2 label

melted_cormat = melted_cormat %>% 
  mutate(names_to_consider=case_when(Var1==Var2 ~ "consider", Var1!=Var2 ~ "no"))

#among those that I narrowed down, I then used my list of names to create a column "names_to_color", and I managed to enter yes on the three names that I wanted. 

#among consider, change the new names to 'yes', and everything else to 'no'

melted_cormat = melted_cormat %>% 
  mutate(names_to_color=case_when(names_to_consider == "consider" & Var1 %in% new_names ~ "yes", 
                                  names_to_consider == "consider" & !(Var1 %in% new_names) ~ "no",
                                  names_to_consider == "no" ~ "no"))

melted_cormat$names_to_color = as.factor(melted_cormat$names_to_color)
#vec_fontface <- ifelse(levels(melted_cormat$names_to_color[melted_cormat$Var2])=="yes","bold","plain")

#plot
ggplot(data = melted_cormat, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill = value))+
  geom_tile(color = "white")+
  geom_text(data=subset(melted_cormat,value < 200), aes(label = value), size=2) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "white", high = "violet", limit = c(0,maximum), space = "Lab", name="key") +
  theme_classic()+ 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color="black", size=10, face="bold.italic"),axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, size = 8, hjust = 1)) +
  coord_fixed() + 
  ggtitle("myplot") +
  scale_y_discrete(labels=c("a"=expression(bold(`a`)), "b"=expression(bold(`b`)),
                            "c"=expression(bold(`c`)), parse=TRUE))
```

Comment: I think this will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39694603/4029270

Comment: Within a `dplyr` pipe on `melted_cormat`, you should never reference `melted_cormat$` again unless you are trying to reset, lose, or somehow otherwise defeat the purpose of the pipe. Just use the variable names, as in `case_when(names_to_consider ...)`.

Comment: Thanks @DanSlone the solution you suggested works and I managed to make the labels bold. However this works great if you have one dataset and you put the names to bold directly in the code. I wanted to refer to a file (new_names) as this file will change from time to time and I won't have to go back into the code and change the names to bold.

Comment: thanks @r2evans I won't be using the ```melted_cormat$``` again in the dplyr pipe.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that using `melted_cormat` within the pipe (like this) is typically wrong. Other reasons when it will fail: if you have `filter` anywhere previous in the pipe; if you do any grouping; if you change any of the variables you are refencing using `melted_cormat$`; if the order of the data changes, whether directly with `arrange` or otherwise. If *any* of those are true, then best-case you will get an error, worst-case (e.g., same number of rows but in different order) is that you will have incorrect results and won't even suspect.

Comment: @Macdonald sure you can always make the element_text() refer to a vector that you create based on the data.  Then the ggplot call can stay the same while your data changes.  Ideally it would be a column in the data frame that was created based on the data condition of interest using case_when() or something like that.

Comment: hi @DanSlone thank you for the response. I did not understand how to fix that in the element_text(). I have modified the original code on the post with the changes we discussed